# App and external links version 12 Android TV and Android Version 12 Smartphone

Tags: android-tv, android-12

I'm creating an app from both my phone and Android TV but I have a problem that I can't solve: the app can't open external links automatically but you have to go through the authorization of the Android operating system (version 12 ). Can you tell me if I can set up the application by bypassing this setting?

I'm trying to associate access via QRCode of an application created for Android TV on smartphones with the same application but dedicated for them for direct authentication.

Comment: Can you show an example of this already on Android TV or somewhere else?